# Find out where item was found using COUNTIF

Tags: vba, excel

I have a two worksheets that I am trying to compare and see if the values from wksht1 are found in wksht2.

```
For Each c In wksht2 
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksht1, c.Value) > 0 Then
        sh2.Range("j10") = c.Value
    End If
Next
```

This returns the value that was found in wksht1, if it was found. 
For example:
Let's say I have two lists

List 1:

> Name:1, Name3, Name17, Name85

List 2:

> Name12, Name6, Name3

Comparing list 2 with list 1, I would find that "Name3" is found in list 1, and the function above would return "Name3" in cell J10.

But I need to also determine WHERE it was found... For instance, in this example, the placement of "Name3" in list 1 would be position 2.

So, how I can search for a string, and if it was found, determine the cell that it was found in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will find the address of the first occurrence of a given `val`

```
Function where(rng As Range, val As Variant) As String
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = rng.Find(val)
   If r Is Nothing Then
       where = val & " was not found"
   Else
      where = r.address
   End If
End Function

Sub TestIt()
    Debug.Print where(Sheet1.UsedRange, "abcde")
End Sub
```

EDIT: Here's a version that will get you all the matched addresses in a comma-separated string (csv):

```
Function whereAll(rng As Range, val As Variant) As String
    Dim r As Range, firstFound As String
    Set r = rng.Find(val)
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    firstFound = r.address
    Do
        whereAll = whereAll & "," & r.address
        Set r = rng.FindNext(r)
    Loop Until r.address = firstFound
    whereAll = Mid(whereAll, 2, 100000)
End Function
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this code and find more than the first occurrence? For instance, if you found the name, but wanted to continue to check if it was found again?

Comment: No, I understand that I can't put all that in J10, but that certainly does help. Thank you for the information, and the answer. This is perfect.

Comment: @Apolymoxic I added a version that finds all matched addresses in a csv :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!